# Find a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{C^*}$ such that $\mathrm{im} f=\langle z \rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Let $$z=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$$

Find a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{C^*}$ such that $\mathrm{im} f=\langle z \rangle$

Struggling to figure out how to start solving this, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What about $\;f(k):=e^{\frac{2k\pi i}7}\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ ...?

Comment: what's $H$ got to do with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any abelian group $G$, we have a natural bijection (in fact an isomorphism of groups)

$$Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}( \mathbb{Z}, G) \to G.$$
Explicitly, this is given by evaluating a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to G$ at $1$. The inverse is given by $g \mapsto (f:n \mapsto ng)$.

It follows then that for any $z \in \mathbb{C}^*$ there is a unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ sending $1$ to $z$. What then is the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{C}^*$?